# How npm detects which node packages are installed on a Windows machine?

Tags: node.js, npm

I wonder if there is an explanation somewhere (maybe on node js website) about the next situation related to packages:

- I installed a sample application, let's say in **d:\samples\backbone** directory, meaning that also the node packages were created there.
- Listing the installed packages with **npm list** from command line in  **d:\samples\backbone\option2** directory will show me the installed packages, the same if I run in **d:\samples\backbone**. If running in **d:\samples** directory, the packages are not shown anymore.

I guess that node searches for installed packages in all directories up to the root, but is somewhere in docs mentioned about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Node.js' documentation, on the modules page - http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html - take a look at the sections:

- Core Modules
- File Modules
- Loading from node_modules Folders

You'll find how `require()` is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Any globally installed modules (for exmaple: npm install -g express) are installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules`

Anything that has been locally installed (such as async, mysql), is placed in your directory inside a `./node_modules/` folder.

In this case, your backbone app has local dependancies, so its packages are installed locally inside **d:\samples\backbone\node_modules**

Comment: It seems to me that if I install the packages in d:\, they will be "seen" from any child directory from d:. Where can I read about this?

Comment: As it is said in [Modules - All together](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together): _To get the exact filename that will be loaded when `require()` is called, use the `require.resolve()` function._